# bit shift operation does not return expected result

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Why does Java return *-2147483648* when I bit shift *1 << 63* ?

The expected result is `9 223 372 036 854 775 808`, tested with Wolfram Alpha and my calculator.

I tested:

```
System.out.print((long)(1 << (63)));
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's an important thing to note about the line

```
System.out.print((long)(1 << (63)));
```

You first take `(1 << 63)`, and *then* you cast to long.  As a result, you are actually left-shifting in integers, so the long cast doesn't have any effect.  That's why shifting 63 bits left gives the min integer rather than the min long.

But there's another, more important point.  Java longs are always signed, so even the line

```
System.out.print(1L << 63);
```

would give a negative number.  Under two's complement, whenever the leftmost bit is a 1 the number is negative.

You actually cannot represent the number 2<sup>63</sup> = 9223372036854775808 in a Java primitive type, because that number is bigger than the maximum long, and `long` is the largest primitive type.  You can represent this number as a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), though.  You can even generate it via a left-shift by 63 with the code

```
BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(63)
```

Comment: +1 for a great answer, which also includes practical solution. p.s. I hope you don't mind I took the liberty to edit 2^63 into something more readable.

Comment: Sure you can represent 2^63 as a long, some operations will interpret is as negative but for most math signedness is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

You are having an [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) [twice].

```
1 << 32 == 1
1 << 31 == -2147483648 [ becuase this is the binary representation in 2's complement for -2147483648]
1 << 63 == 1 << (32 + 31) == (1 << 32) << 31 == 1 << 31 == -2147483648
```

When you do `(long)(1 << (63))` you are only casting the result of `1 << (63)` [which is `-2147483648`] to a `long` - and it does not change its value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out and describing the overflowing!  I've been looking for an explanation to this code found on OpenJDK's BitSet implementation: [ long firstWordMask = WORD_MASK << fromIndex;   long lastWordMask  = WORD_MASK >>> -toIndex; ] even though in this case WORD_MASK is long.